# There's a [password-encryption] tag in my Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki

Encrypting a password is a bad idea. People still do it. People will ask about it on SO. They will (hopefully get an answer telling them why it's a bad idea).

So all in all, I think that the existence of this tag is better than the alternative (which is that there will still be questions about the topic, but they can't easily be identified).

**But**, the tag wiki (and it's summary) of [password-encryption](/questions/tagged/password-encryption) is ... lacking, to be honest. I think this tag could really profit from a well-written summary of the issues of this topic (and ideally a prototypical question/answer "How do I encrypt my passwords?").

Comment: So....write it?

Comment: I was afraid that this would come. But that's not really my area. I know *in general* what should be done, but I don't feel I have enough in-depth knowledge to write the authoritative wiki on this topic.

Comment: Temporary suggestion: **thou shalt not encrypt passwords.** (or maybe we can find a SO or Security.SE question dealing with the topic, and link to that?)

Comment: I'm sympathetic to that feeling, for certain, but it's probably better to have an in-general pass such as you or I might write than what's there now. And it would provide a framework for more knowledgeable people to improve. That's the virtue of wikis.

Comment: I just made a quick edit along the lines suggested by @Pekka. Smarter folks are encouraged to do better.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It was admittedly a bit tongue-in-cheek. ;) But perhaps starting an outline might not be beyond your abilities? Perhaps that would attract attention/help?

Comment: I've added to the tag wiki.